# Any good Focus Stacking software apart from Hugin +Enfuse

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, photography, photo-editing

I been trying to find some good  software to allow me to align + focus Stack pictures but seems like there is not many around any suggestions? using ubuntu 14.04 LTS